# Exception sending context initialized event to listener

Tags: spring, security

I am using spring mvc to create restful webservices.When i integrate Spring security to the code I got the below error

```
StackTrace:

SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appointmentController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.nutansTplus.service.AppointmentService com.nutansTplus.controller.AppointmentController.appointmentService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.nutansTplus.service.AppointmentService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=appointmentService)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.nutansTplus.service.AppointmentService com.nutansTplus.controller.AppointmentController.appointmentService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.nutansTplus.service.AppointmentService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=appointmentService)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.nutansTplus.service.AppointmentService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=appointmentService)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:920)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:789)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
```

and my web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>NutansTplus-BackEnd</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/service/version_1.0/object/account/resourcenotfound</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/service/version_1.0/object/account/unauthorised</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/service/version_1.0/object/account/unauthorised</location>
</error-page>
</web-app>
```

And my **Security-beans.xml** is as follows
  WEB-INF/security-beans.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nutansTplus.controller" />
    <!-- Security configuration for REST services. -->
    <security:http 
        authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" auto-config="true">
        <security:custom-filter ref="restServicesFilter"
            before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
              <security:intercept-url pattern="/services/data/v1.0/Restaurant/GetRestaurantsDetails" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
          <security:intercept-url pattern="/services/data/v1.0/Restaurant/PostFeedbackDetail" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    </security:http>

    <!-- Entry point for REST service. -->
<!--    <bean id="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="com.nutansR.controller.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
 -->    <!-- Filter for REST services. -->
    <bean id="restServicesFilter"
        class="com.nutansTplus.controller.RestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="postOnly" value="false" />
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="restServicesSuccessHandler" />
    </bean>
    <!-- A handler for successful REST service authentication. -->
    <bean id="restServicesSuccessHandler" class="com.nutansTplus.controller.RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
    <!-- Security configuration for other resources. Use login form. -->
    <!-- <security:http use-expressions="true" create-session="always">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />
    </security:http> -->
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="admin_user" password="password"
                    authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <security:user name="karthi" password="karthi"
                    authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
    <security:global-method-security
        secured-annotations="enabled"
    proxy-target-class="true">
    </security:global-method-security>
</beans>
```

And my application-context.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <import resource="spring/security-beans.xml" />

</beans>
```

And my spring-servlet.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
 xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
 xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">
 <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nutansTplus"/>

       <context:annotation-config />
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.nutansTplus.pushService" />
        <task:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
 </bean>
 <bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:Application.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
 <bean id="nutansRegisterDao" class="com.nutansTplus.dao.NutansRegisterDao"/>
 <bean id="appointmentDAO" class="com.nutansTplus.dao.AppointmentDAO"/>
 <bean id="commonDAO" class="com.nutansTplus.dao.CommonDAO"/>

<bean id="dataSource1" destroy-method="close" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
<property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
<property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
<property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
<property name="minPoolSize" value="10"/>
<property name="maxPoolSize" value="150"/>
<property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="false"/>
<property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="3"/>
<property name="maxStatements" value="100"/>
<property name="maxIdleTime" value="3600"/>
<property name="acquireIncrement" value="10"/>
<property name="preferredTestQuery" value="select 1 from DUAL" />
<property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="180" />
<property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true" />
</bean>
    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"> 
    <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource1"/></property> 
</bean> 
<bean id="ndPjdbcTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource1"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
<bean id="MyServlet" class="com.nutansTplus.dao.NutansRegisterDao"> 
    <property name="jdbcTemplate"><ref bean="jdbcTemplate"/></property> 
</bean> 
<bean id="commonDao" class="com.nutansTplus.dao.CommonDAO"> 
    <property name="jdbcTemplate"><ref bean="jdbcTemplate"/></property> 
</bean> 
<bean id="dynamicFormDao" class="com.nutansTplus.dao.DynamicFormDAO">
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
        <property name="namedParamJdbcTemplate" ref="ndPjdbcTemplate" />
    </bean> 
  </beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that Spring could not create bean `appointmentController` because class `AppointmentController` contains something like :

```
Autowired(required=true)
Qualifier(value=appointmentService)
AppointmentService appointmentService;
```

I presume that `AppointmentService` is a class and not an interface. Spring makes heavy use of AOP proxies and by default uses JDK proxies => meaning you must autowire by **interface** because a JDK proxy does implement the interface but does not extend the class.

My advice is use interfaces if possible because it gives highly maintenable code because you can easily change an implementation.

For example you service could become :

```
class AppointmentServiceImpl implements AppointmentService {
    ...
}
```

If you cannot you can try to use `proxy-target-class=true` but be sure to use it consistently in all places where Spring will use AOP proxying (the reason why my advise is to stick to Spring default JDK proxies ... )